# Spring Controller: use domain objects as @RequestBody

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a domain object class `User` (it is a JPA entity):

```
@Entity
public class User {
   private String name;
   private boolean enabled = true;
   // getters/setters
}
```

And I am trying to offer a REST API to allow clients to create new users, using Spring 3 MVC:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createRealm(@RequestBody User user) {
            user.setEnabled(true); // client is not allowed to modify this field
            userService.createUser(user);
            ...
    }
}
```

It works great, but I do not know if it is a good idea to **use the domain objects as @RequestBody**, because I have to protect some fields that should not be directly modified by the client (i.e. "enabled" in this case).

What are the pros/cons of these alternatives:

1. Use the **domain objects** and protect the fields the user is not allowed to modify (for example set them to null or to its default value by hand)
2. Use a **new set of auxiliar objects** (something similar to a DTO), such as a UserRequest that only contains the fields I want to expose through the REST API, and map them (i.e. with [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)) to the domain objects.

The second alternative looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   private String name;
   private boolean enabled = true;
   // getters/setters
}

public class UserRequest {
   private String name;
   // enabled is removed
   // getters/setters
}

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createRealm(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
            User user = ... // map UserRequest -> User
            userService.createUser(user);
            ...
    }
}
```

Is there any other way that avoids code duplication and is easier to maintain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another option - you can disallow the submission of a given set of properties, using the [`DataBinder.setDisallowedFields(..)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html) (or using `.setAllowedFields(..)`)

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields(..);
}
```

This is fine if you have one or two properties that differ.

Otherwise, having a special object (like `ProfileDetails` or `UserRequest`) makes more sense. I am using such a DTO-like object for this scenario and then transfer the fields with `BeanUtils.copyProperties(..)` from commons-beanutils

A third, perhaps better option, is to put all profile-related fields into a separate entity (mapped with `@OneToOne` with user) or to an `@Embeddable` object, and use it instead.

Comment: Great answer Bozho, thank you. What do you think about creating a Disallowed annotation to annotate the fields you don't want to expose (I think Spring doesn't offer anything like that), and call binder.setDisallowedFields(MyUtils.findDisallowedFields(User.class))?  An Allowed annotation could be even safer.

Comment: Sorry I'm bothering you.  Do you think it is a good place to use some kind of AOP pointcut maybe?

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a `WebBindingInitializer`

Comment: @Bozho I heard initbinder wont work with RequestBody . I tried to do so also, it is not setting up  bindingResult.getSuppressedFields(). can you please help on this?Is there any additional things to do for this?