# Spring WebDataBinder.setDisallowedFields for @RequestBody

Tags: spring

Does *WebDataBinder.setDisallowedFields* work with *@RequestBody*?

This question has been asked before but there are conflicting answers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040293/spring-controller-use-domain-objects-as-requestbody) it's said it works, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680960/spring-initbinder-on-requestbody) and also in a few more places it's said it doesn't work.

I've tried it with Spring 3 and 4 and found it doesn't work. Maybe this requires some additional setup?

Sample code:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setDisallowedFields("name");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody 
    public Response add(@RequestBody Request request) {
        return new Response("added name: " + request.name + ", surname: " + request.surname);
    }

    public static class Request {
        String name, surname;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }

    public static class Response {
        final String message;

        Response(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No... Binding and marshaling are different things...

Comment: Agree. But it's weird in the first link the accepted answer says it works and has 5 upvotes.

Comment: That is simply wrong, it doesn't work and never will work. `DataBinder` is for use with `@ModelAttribute` only not for `@RequestBody` that uses `HttpMessageConverter`s and not a `DataBinder`. So again it will not work and the answer simply remains *no*.